# How to start Docker from command line on Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm working on a shell script, which from the user's OS, will run a series of commands to open docker, if the user has it already installed, if the user doesn't have it, it will install docker and only after installing docker script will open it.

I've already made the script for MacOs, the linux and windows part is missing, but I can't find anywhere that shows a command that opens docker on linux.

On windows I believe you just install docker and run the .exe

I don't have a linux, so I haven't tried anything yet.

Hope you have a command line that runs and opens Docker on linux.

Comment: there are around 500-600 more or less different linuxes, which ones you target?

Comment: @IłyaBursov the shell script catch the OS system with the "popular" name, so the target of the script will get all the linux distros.
I only want the command with execute the Docker with CLI comand.

Comment: How do you run in MacOS ?

Comment: `docker run …`?

Comment: @Philippe run `open -a Docker.app` in the terminal

Comment: @knittl thats run and Open the Docker in your terminal Linux?

Comment: @DouglasFernandes I don't know what "open and run the docker" means. That commands starts a docker container for an image by name

Comment: @knittl so I think the command I want doesnt exist in linux. I found this command too, but doesnt does what I want

Comment: This might help : https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/#:~:text=To%20start%20Docker%20Desktop%20for,the%20status%20of%20Docker%20Desktop.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe thats possível have I want. This command `systemctl --user start docker-desktop` in the doc maybe solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `systemctl --user start docker-desktop` it's start the Docker with the CLI.